# How do i prevent the value of a child component class variable from being overwritten when multiple component instances are used on the same page?

Tags: angular, class, variables, components, mat-tab

I have a Child Component that has a class variable called `emptyMessage`. In the `ngOnInit()` method the value of this variable is set. I use multiple instances of the same child component in one parent component. What i have discovered is that `emptyMessage` will get the same value across all of the child component instances on that page. The value is determined by the last child component that is initialized.
I am displaying these child components in a `mat-tab-group` component. All child component instances are loaded in a separate `mat-tab` window and the contents of each `mat-tab` window are loaded eagerly.

I'm not sure whether this behaviour is caused by `mat-tab-group` or by angular itself. I know that in Java whenever you define a `class variable` as `static` then that variable and its value are shared amongst all the instances that are made from that class. If the class variables of an angular component are static by default, is there any way to turn them into instance variables so that different component instances can have their own separate values?

EDIT: code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  emptyMessage:string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emptyMessage = new Date().getTime().toString();
  }
}



html file 

<p>{{emptyMessage}}</p>
```

Parent component HTML

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="child component copy 1">
        <app-child></app-child>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="child component copy 2">
        <app-child></app-child>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="child component copy 3">
        <app-child></app-child>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The value of emptyMessage for all 3 child components should be the value that was assigned by the last child component that was initialized, in this case the instance in `child component copy 3` mat-tab.

Answer (score 1):

They don't share the value - each property declared within a component is scoped to that component. It just so happens that it generates the same value three times.

That is because the contents of each tab is loaded eagerly, they are initialized at the exact same time.

I've prepared a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imfimy) with your use case, with additional `counter` property which uses incremental counter. I've also added a case where tab contents are lazily loaded as well.

Comment: I found out what the problem was... I was initializing `emptyMessage` in a switch case that had a component input variable as its condition. The reason why the value was the same for all components was because i forgot to add `break;` to each `case`. That was a silly mistake!